# Pandas equivalent of dplyr everything()

Tags: r, pandas, dplyr

In R I frequently use `dplyr`'s `select` in combination with `everything()`

```
df %>% select(var4, var17, everything())
```

The above for example would reorder the columns of the dataframe, such that `var4` is the first, `var17` is the second and subsequently all remaining columns are listed. What is the most pandathonic way of doing this?  Working with many columns makes explicitly spelling them out a pain as well as keeping track of their position.

The ideal solution is short, readable and can be used in pandas chaining.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) for all values without specified in list and join together:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'G':list('abcdef'),
         'var17':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'A':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'var4':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

cols = ['var4','var17']
another = df.columns.difference(cols, sort=False).tolist()
df = df[cols + another]
print (df)
   var4  var17  G  A  E  F
0     1      4  a  7  5  a
1     3      5  b  8  3  a
2     5      4  c  9  6  a
3     7      5  d  4  9  b
4     1      5  e  2  2  b
5     0      4  f  3  4  b
```

EDIT: For chaining is possible use [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) with passed `DataFrame`:

```
def everything_after(df, cols):
    another = df.columns.difference(cols, sort=False).tolist()
    return df[cols + another]

df = df.pipe(everything_after, ['var4','var17']))
print (df)
   var4  var17  G  A  E  F
0     1      4  a  7  5  a
1     3      5  b  8  3  a
2     5      4  c  9  6  a
3     7      5  d  4  9  b
4     1      5  e  2  2  b
5     0      4  f  3  4  b
```

Comment: this works as described, but takes quite some lines of code. Also, this will be difficult to work into a panda chaining of commands. I will accept the the solution if no one can provide a "shorter" version.

Comment: put differently: is there a way to define this as a function and reuse it whenever necessary. i.e. define a `everything_after(var4, var17)` to get the output above

Comment: great! would make for a nice feature request for pandas, but I will leave it to the pros...

Comment: one very last request: Can we modify this to use with chaining? Smth like: `df.query('A > 3').everything_after(['var4','var17'])`

Comment: @SAFEX - Not this way, need `everything_after(df.query('A > 3'), ['var4','var17'])`

Comment: hm I see. To mimic dplyr behaviour as close as possible, I would have preferred it the other way. I am trying to use `.pipe` to get it to work,  but failed so far

Comment: for ```pipe```, u dont need the lambda, :```df.pipe(everything_after, ["var4","var17"])``` should suffice

Answer (score 3):

Now how smoothly you can do it with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar)!

```py
>>> from datar import f
>>> from datar.datasets import iris
>>> from datar.dplyr import select, everything, slice_head
>>> iris >> slice_head(5)
   Sepal_Length  Sepal_Width  Petal_Length  Petal_Width Species
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
4           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2  setosa
>>> iris >> select(f.Species, everything()) >> slice_head(5)
  Species  Sepal_Length  Sepal_Width  Petal_Length  Petal_Width
0  setosa           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2
1  setosa           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2
2  setosa           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2
3  setosa           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2
4  setosa           5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.